# multipassd uses 100% of cpu core

Tags: 18.04, cpu-load, multipass

I run Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Dell Latitude 5491

After each restart the cooling fan works hard. The CPU usage is about 100% for one core by multipassd.

```
%CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
99,7  0,3   1:18.97 multipassd
```

After restarting multipassd...

```
sudo snap restart multipass.multipassd
```

...it goes back to normal.

Multipass version is 0.8.1

```
# multipass --version
multipass  0.8.1
multipassd 0.8.1
```

Could anybody please help me why this thing happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a standard Ubuntu package?

Comment: It's a Canonical product used for snap packages. We use snap packages as a tool for deployment of pieces of software created and running in Ubuntu environment. Snapcraft uses multipass. (you can have some info about it here : `https://multipass.run/` and here : `https://snapcraft.io/multipass`)